# What alternatives do i have if i like to embed video player in to Qt and not to be GPL?

Tags: qt, embed, media-player

Hello 
basccly  i need to be able to play youtube videos in desktop application that is not GPL
i was reading that it can be done with LibVLC , but its GPL and its a problem 
do i have any alternatives?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't give much facts of what you actually need from the video side and you state that you are using QT, why not to go with its own media stuff - Phonon?

Comment: Phonon is only wrapper , the backed needs to be some kind of player
that is usually GPL

Comment: The thing is, QT is licensed as LGPL. So in order to use it, you would already be required to fulfill its licensing rules.   On linux your backend would be GStreamer if  you where to use phonon. Once again, it is LGPL. For other os's phonon will use quicktime & directx.